# Transform this to one line arrow function ES6+

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using one line arrow functions a lot, if they are well written I believe they can make code easier to read. I believe that the following code can be easily transformed into one liner but I can't figure out how. Any ideas please? I am asking more just from curiosity.

```javascript
const getUID = async () => {
  let uid;
  await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
    if (!user) await firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
    uid = user.uid;
  });
  return uid;
};
```

Comment: No, it can't, and probably shouldn't. The real problem is that `onAuthStateChanged` expects a callback and is supposed to be used as an observable that **can fire multiple times**, but you're trying to use it as a promise, waiting for the first change only. You would need to immediately unsubscribe, similar to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47043188/1048572). Also you should not pass an `async`  function as a callback.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I forget that `onAuthStateChanged` is not one time job. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: There is no syntactic rule that would force you to use new line characters. You can write entire applications as one liners. Whether you should is a different story. Don't let number of lines become your holy grail.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `onAuthStateChanged` expects a callback and **can be fired multiple times**. To resolve that you can use `unsubscribe()` after the first success.

Secondly, for your code to work, you need to wait for `signInAnonymously`. At the moment you assign it to a temporary variable, but I can't see it working. Because `onAuthStateChanged` accepts a callback that can be fired multiple times, it won't wait in the main scope. To solve this, I suggest using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) constructor.

Finally, you call `signInAnonymously`, but you don't do anything with its response. You need to use `user.uid` if the user is logged in, otherwise you need to use `signInAnonymously().user.uid`

So the final solution:

```js
const getUID = async () => new Promise(resolve => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user ? user.uid : firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(v => v.user.uid))
    });
})

const uid = await getUID()
```

Explanation:

1. Wrap everything to [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and resolve it when we get `uid`
2. Auth & listen on `onAuthStateChanged`
3. Unsubscribe on the first `onAuthStateChanged` callback trigger (because one trigger it's enough in your case)
4. Check if a user is defined (that means the user is signed in), resolve promise with user `uid`
5. If the user is not defined, use `signInAnonymously` to sign anonymous user, resolve that user `uid.